# Problems cropping entire white lines from .png file

Tags: python, set, python-imaging-library, crop

What I want to do is to crop out the white lines above a given instagram print screen. I tried doing that by finding the center of the image and going up, line by line, until I found the first line entirely white. Any idea why my code is not working?

```
from PIL import Image

image_file = "test.png"
im = Image.open(image_file)
width, height = im.size
centerLine = height // 2

entireWhiteLine = set()
entireWhiteLine.add(im.getpixel((0, 0)))
terminateUpperCrop = 1

while terminateUpperCrop != 2 :

    for i in range(centerLine, 1, -1) :
        entireLine = set()
        upperBorder = i - 1
        for j in range(0, width, 1) :
            entireLine.add((im.getpixel((i, j))))
            if entireLine == im.getpixel((0,0)):
                box = (0, upperBorder, width, height)
                crop = im.crop((box))
                crop.save('test2.png')
                terminateUpperCrop = 2
```

Comment: A useful thing to do to help people trying to answer your question is to describe what your code is currently doing and how that differs from what you want it to do. Sharing your testing also helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getpixel()` call is actually searching with the coordinates the wrong way around, so in effect you were scanning for the left edge. You could use the following approach. This creates a row of data containing only white pixels. If the length of the row equals your width, then you know they are all white.

```
from PIL import Image

image_file = "test.png"
im = Image.open(image_file)
width, height = im.size
centerLine = height // 2

white = (255, 255, 255)

for y in range(centerLine, 0, -1) :
    if len([1 for x in range(width) if im.getpixel((x, y)) == white]) == width - 1:
        box = (0, y, width, height)
        crop = im.crop((box))
        crop.save('test2.png')
        break
```

Comment: OP here, thank you very much!

Any reason in particular you didn't use sets? Or just for simplicity's sake?

Comment: I would need to test it, but in this case the list might be faster. You could add all pixels to a set and then test the set has a single white entry. Adding items to a set is probably slower than adding items to a list. The list comprehension only adds if the pixel is white, the list itself can contain anything (I chose to add a `1`). By using a list you could for example test if 95% of entries are white as the list length is proportional to the amount of white.